# Font looks bigger when site is deployed

Tags: html, css, font-size

When I deploy my site, the font looks bigger on the server machine than on my local machine, although the css has not changed. I deployed on two different hosts. Searched for a few days but got no solution. Customer service says either scripts are wrong or upload is wrong (try use compress/decompress). Help please!

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  /* font-size:62.5%; */
  background-color: #000;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 6rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
}
```

link:
https://tioung.github.io/fontSerif/

#### On local machine

[image: local machine image]

#### On remote machine

[image: remote machine image]

Thanks and regards
David

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your localhost is at 80% zoom.

Comment: Ouf. You saved my life! Just curious - How did you know it was 80%?

Comment: in the address bar, if the zoom is changed from default  it will show the zoomed percentage https://prnt.sc/11qphyx